# docker-compose игнорирование node_modules

Tags: windows, vue.js, docker

ОС Windows 10, использую docker toolbox

Имеется Dockerfile

```
FROM node:slim
RUN npm install --quiet --global @vue/cli
WORKDIR /www/frontend/vuejs
```

Пытаюсь сделать билд docker-compose.yml:

```
frontend:
  build: ./docker/vue/build
  volumes:
    - ./:/www
  command: bash -c "npm install && npm run build"
```

Но проблема состоит именно в volumes, т.к. командой npm install пытаюсь развернуть проект и на этом этапе падает с ошибками "ETXTBSY: text file is busy, unlink" (даже npm install --no-bin links не помогает)

В принципе если исключить из volumes папку node_modules, то на локалке и хосте будут всегда разные папки, только вот не пойму как именно это сделать. Ведь нужно собирать проект через докер, а запускать разработку с локалки

Answer (score 0):

[Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181032/add-a-volume-to-docker-but-exclude-a-sub-folder) вопрос уже рассмотрен.

Идея:

1. монтируем в docker директорию с проектом
2. перезаписываем в docker'е директорию с модулями Node.js

`volumes:
       - './angularApp:/opt/app'
       - /opt/app/node_modules/`

Comment: Спасибо, но не помогает
Пытался ранее, но он все равно создает папку и выдает такую же ошибку 
"npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename"

проблема не только в маппинга, но и в ОС. В данном случае линуха и винда не дружат